# DjangoCMS: how to make it save CMS migrations in my project folder?

Tags: django, django-cms

I haveto use DjangoCMS. When I cast `makemigrations`, it makes cms migrations and saves them into DjangoCMS library folder. How can I tell Django to save the migrations in my project folder?

Comment: Please provide some more details. What happens if you run `makemigrations` specifically for one of your apps in `INSTALLED_APPS`? If you run `manage.py makemigrations myapp` then you should see the migrations directory added within `myapp`.

Comment: I call `makemigrations myapp`. Then I can see a dependency to some CMS migration into the initial migration of `myapp`. The CMS migration is into CMS folder.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with a dependency on CMS migrations. But you shouldn't be creating new migrations which you rely on in site-packages. Apps you rely on should have up to date migrations. You can just call `migrate myapp` and commit your app's migration.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the versions of django-cms you have installed, there were some missing migrations in earlier versions of the django-cms. This has been fixed in latest versions of `django-cms==3.1.3`.

You can manually change the `dependencies` for your own apps so that it doesn't depend on the missing migrations from cms.

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('cms', '__latest__'),
    ]
```